# Combining XHR request with form test after resizing an image to be uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send both form input text and an image that is being uploaded and resized client side to a php page.

The image is sending fine but when I try to append the text data, it won't work.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = new FormData();
    data = 'image=' + dataURL;
    data.append('Name', 'test');
    xhr.send(data);
```

When I tried appending a string to test it, the data isn't sent at all. However without the append it still sends. How do I append the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you do `data = 'image=' + dataURL;`, you redefine the var `data` as a string. So the append method for the name is failing. I think you have 2 options:

1: Using the formData() constructor:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('image', dataURL);
    data.append('Name', 'test');
    xhr.send(data);
```

2: Not using the formData() constructor:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev){
        document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = 'Done!';
    };

    xhr.open('POST', 'uploadResized.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var data = 'image=' + dataURL + '&Name=test';
    xhr.send(data);
```